# MIPS max moving address of j instruction

Tags: assembly, mips

In class, it was said that the bit of the address part of the j instruction is encoded by appending two 0 bits to the end and four MSBs from the PC in front.

However, one thing I don't understand is the part where 4 MSBs are attached.

If the current PC is 0x20000000 and so on.

If the command j 0x3ffffff  is given, will the final address that j arrives at is 00101111....11100 with the first 4 bits of the PC, 0010, followed by two 0 bits?

```
j 0x3ffffff

0x3fffff

-> convert to binary

11111111111111111111111111

-> add two zero bits at the end. (<< 2)

1111111111111111111111111100
-> add PC's four MSB bits.

00101111111111111111111111111100 <- Is this right encoding???
```

Comment: `0x3ffffff` is not a valid target address, since the two lsb:s are non-zero. If the assembler accepts that, then it will hopefully warn you about his. As for what the actual destination would end up being.. presumably `0x23FFFFFC` (with the instruction word being `0x04FFFFFF`).

Answer (score 0):

> 00101111111111111111111111111100 <- Is this right encoding???

No, this is not an encoding — this is simply an address<sup>1</sup>, a potential pc value, aka a branch target, value 0x2FFFFFFC.

We use the term encoding for data that field encoded (multiple fields) — and as an address this is simply a single value.

One common and typical use for encoding is instructions.

The encoding for a `j` instruction would have 6 opcode bits, value 0x2, and 26 bit immediate, so encode as two fields:

```
opcode          immediate
000010 | 11111111111111111111111111
```

And this encoded instruction will reach the branch target address you mention above, assuming the pc is already in the 0010 range (its upper bits are 0010).

A good way to ask your hypothetical would be to avoid the assembler and assembler syntax altogether, and say something like:  Assuming the pc has upper 4 bits of 0010 and we want to branch to location 0x2FFFFFFC, how do we encode the instruction, and/or vice versa let's say we processor executes 0x0BFFFFFF (the single value of the encoded instruction) with the PC having upper 4 bits of 0010, what address will it branch to?

A reason to factor out the assembler is because there are multiple assemblers for each architecture (potentially); MIPS, for example, has at least 3.  The MARS assembler won't even take a numeric argument for the operand of a `j` instruction.  So, the syntax and meaning of lines of assembly throws another set of manuals at the hypothetical.

---

<sup>1</sup>  Can we break down an address into fields?  Yes, of course.  The low two bits must be even, so we can argue that is a field, and, the high 4 bits are consumed in execution of `j` type instructions, so that's a field.  Further, if you get into cache operation, an address is decomposed in cache lookup into tag, index, block offset   — which are yet different fields; addresses are also viewed as field encoded in translation of virtual addresses to physical.  Still we would most normally call an address a (simple unencoded, single) value.